How to get the current monitor of a window in js
I save the position of a window when it's closed:
const savePositionToStorage = (position) => {
    localStorage.setItem('windowPosition', position);
    console.log('Position saved:', position);
}

const getPositionFromStorage = () => {
    const position = localStorage.getItem('windowPosition');
    return position ? position :  "top=0,left=0,width=800,height=1000";
}

and open a window like this:
const handleExpandClick = (id) => {
    const windowFeatures = getPositionFromStorage();

    const pdfWindow = window.open(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/transactions/matching_evidence/${id}#toolbar=0,view=FitH`,
        "pdf",
        windowFeatures,
    );

    pdfWindow.onload = () => {
        pdfWindow.onbeforeunload = () => {
            savePositionToStorage(`top=${pdfWindow.screenY},left=${pdfWindow.screenX},height=${pdfWindow.innerHeight},width=${pdfWindow.innerWidth}`)
        }
    }

}

The user should be able to save the current location and size of the window, so the user doesn't have to readjust the pop-up every time.
It works with the current browser monitor, but if I close it on another monitor, it will simply pop up on the furthest right of the current browser monitor.
Is there a way to archive what I want?
Chrome would be the browser the users are using.

Your code works fine, assuming the website allows the CORS policy. Are you sure you enabled that?

@Jake is it saving the position of the second monitor too?
How can I check if the Cors policy is allowed?

After const pdfWindow = window.open(...), write pdfWindow.window.onload. If it gives you an error, then the cors policy isn't allowed.

const pdfWindow = window.open(
http://127.0.0.1:8000/transactions/matching_evidence/${id}#toolbar=0,view=FitH,
"pdf",
windowFeatures,
);
pdfWindow.window.onload
This way? No error there

After const pdfWindow... do window.pdfwindow = pdfwindow. After running handleExpandClick(), try x.onload. If it gives you An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent., then CORS isn't enabled. Sorry, the earlier was wrong.

I did it this way:
window.pdfwindow = pdfWindow
window.pdfwindow.onload = () => {
    console.log("tes");
}

the log is printed, and no error.
Thanks for taking the time to try to help ;)

Does ScreenDetails give enough info? Chrome/WebKit experimental feature only available in a secure context, so it may be difficult to make use of.

@l3l_aze this throws this error: DOMException: Transient activation is required to request permission. But I can't seem to find what I have to do to grant the permissions

That means the action that causes a request for permission has to be done through user interaction, and can't be automated. Transient activation on MDN.

For some reason, it works now.
I deleted the local storage, and when I tried again, it just worked.
I didn't really change anything, except that I'm saving the data as a stringnifyed json:
const savePositionToStorage = (position) => {
    localStorage.setItem('windowPosition', JSON.stringify(position));
    console.log('Position saved:', position);
}

const getPositionFromStorage = () => {
    const position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('windowPosition'));
    return position ? position : { top: 0, left: 0, width: 800, height: 1000 };
}


// #region Click Events
const handleExpandClick = async (id) => {
    const storedPosition = getPositionFromStorage();
    const windowFeatures = `top=${storedPosition.top},left=${storedPosition.left},height=${storedPosition.height},width=${storedPosition.width}`;

    const pdfWindow = window.open(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/transactions/matching_evidence/${id}#toolbar=0,view=FitH`,
        "pdf",
        windowFeatures,
    );


    pdfWindow.onload = () => {
        pdfWindow.onbeforeunload = () => {
            savePositionToStorage({ "top": pdfWindow.screenY, "left": pdfWindow.screenX, "height": pdfWindow.innerHeight, "width": pdfWindow.innerWidth })
        }
    }
}
// #endregion

I will ask my colleagues to try the code later and I'll report back if it works there.
Very strange
Edit:
Okay, the problem seems to be Window management. This has to be set to allow.
I don't know how to get the permissions yet
Edit:
I found the problem now.
I simply needed to wait for the promise and go from there (full code):
Be aware that this won't work with FireFox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getScreenDetails
// #windowLocation
const savePositionToStorage = (position) => {
    localStorage.setItem('windowPosition', JSON.stringify(position));
}

const getPositionFromStorage = () => {
    const position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('windowPosition'));
    return position ? position : { top: 0, left: 0, width: 800, height: 1000 };
}

const loadWindow = (windowFeatures, id) => {
    const pdfWindow = window.open(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/transactions/matching_evidence/${id}#toolbar=0,view=FitH`,
        "pdf",
        windowFeatures,
    );

    pdfWindow.onload = () => {
        pdfWindow.onbeforeunload = () => {
            savePositionToStorage({ "top": pdfWindow.screenY, "left": pdfWindow.screenX, "height": pdfWindow.innerHeight, "width": pdfWindow.innerWidth })
        }
    }
}
// #endregion


// #region Click Events
const handleExpandClick = (id) => {
    const storedPosition = getPositionFromStorage();
    const windowFeatures = `top=${storedPosition.top},left=${storedPosition.left},height=${storedPosition.height},width=${storedPosition.width}`;

    // if there are multiple screens, ask the user for window Management permissions.
    // supported browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getScreenDetails
    if (window.screen.isExtended) {
        window.getScreenDetails().then(() => {
            loadWindow(windowFeatures, id);
        });
    } else {
        loadWindow(windowFeatures, id);
    }
}
// #endregion

